# Tomcat: allow UTF-8 in headers, instead of ISO-8859-1

Tags: tomcat, encoding, utf-8, header

I receive Headers from my Identity Provider which include UTF-8 characters. This cannot be changed.

Tomcat automatically parses these headers as ISO-8859-1.

How can I change this behaviour, and allow UTF-8 headers in Tomcat?

Please do not suggest to encode the ISO-8859-1 back to UTF-8 in my application, this is not an option in my case, hence none of the many suggestions I can find on the internet work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check this https://users.tomcat.apache.narkive.com/pQO0C6z0/incorrect-decoding-of-encoded-http-headers

As per https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987

> By default, message header field parameters in HTTP ([RFC2616])
> messages cannot carry characters outside the ISO-8859-1 character set
> ([ISO-8859-1])